# Mockery ordered mocks

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

So basically I trying to mock my dependencies on a controller and I want to use the `ordered()` feature of Mockery.

```
    $request = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Http\Request');
    $response = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Http\Response');
    $response->shouldReceive("setContent")->ordered();

    $db = \Mockery::mock('Dabble\Database');

    $configData = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Configuration\ConfigurationData');
    $configData->shouldReceive("get")->andReturn(array(18, 23))->ordered();
```

The above test is successful even though the the `$configData->get()` is being called before `$response->setContent()` in the controller. 
Moreover if I reverse the order of the mocks I still geta successful test.

```
    $request = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Http\Request');

    $db = \Mockery::mock('Dabble\Database');

    $configData = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Configuration\ConfigurationData');
    $configData->shouldReceive("get")->andReturn(array(18, 23))->ordered();

    $response = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Http\Response');
    $response->shouldReceive("setContent")->ordered();
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ordering only applies to the same Mock, unless you use the `globally()` method to make the order work with distinct mocks.

Try

```
$request = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Http\Request');
$response = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Http\Response');
$response->shouldReceive("setContent")->globally()->ordered();

$db = \Mockery::mock('Dabble\Database');

$configData = \Mockery::mock('Silhouette\Configuration\ConfigurationData');
$configData->shouldReceive("get")->andReturn(array(18, 23))->globally()->ordered();
```

This is explained in the docs:

[http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html](https://github.com/padraic/mockery/blob/master/docs/06-EXPECTATION%20DECLARATIONS.md)

Comment: Declares that this method is expected to be called in a specific order in relation to similarly marked methods.
So they mean methods of the same mocked object. Thanks!